# Show that $\|v\|v$ is totally differentiable at the origin.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

As it says in the title, let $(V, \| . \|)$ be a normed Banach space of finite dimension.
Show that the mapping $\| v \|v$ is differentiable at the origin.

I wish I could say I've managed to accomplish something but up to this point, I only know I need to find a linear mapping whose derivative approaches zero and a remainder function whose limit approaches zero. Note that $v$ is an element of a Banach space.

Comment: The derivative is the zero map!

Comment: I know the directional derivative is the zero map but when showing total differentiability, the remainder function should be taken into account.

Comment: Please state your question in the *body* of your post, not just in the title.

Comment: Also, use `\| v \|` for better spacing of norm bars: $\| v \|$.

Comment: Can you write an explicit formula for the remainder function $r(v)$? Then try to show that $r(v)/\|v\| \to 0$ as $v \to 0$.

Comment: @SammyBlack Done

Comment: Are you talking about the Fréchet derivative?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes, I am talking about the Fréchet derivative.

Comment: Then isn't the only thing you need to show, in light of the claim that the derivative is $0$ at the origin, that $\lim_{\|v\| \to 0} \frac{\|(\|v\|v)\|}{\|v\|} = 0$?

Answer (score 0):

Define $f(v)=\|v\|\cdot v$. To prove that the derivative at the origin is $A$ we should show that:
$$\lim_{v\to 0}\frac{\|f(v)-f(0)-A(v)\|}{\|v\|} = 0.$$ As @Kavi pointed out, $A$ is zero map, so we need to prove that:
$$\lim_{v\to 0}\frac{\|f(v)-f(0)\|}{\|v\|} = 0.$$
Can you show this equality?

Comment: I have a question.. Does $A(v)$ map to zero everywhere or just when $v = 0$?

Comment: @Kaind The derivative at a point is always a linear map, so $A(0)=0$ no matter what $A$ is, but in this case, $A$ is the derivative at the origin, and this derivative is the zero map, so $A(v)=0$ for all $v$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(v) = v\|v\|$. We have $|f(v)| = \|v\|^2$, so $f(v) = f(0) + 0v + O(\|v\|^2)$. Thus, by definition of derivative, $Df(0) = 0$.